# Excel formula returning multiple values according to two criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula (without VBA) that could provide the list of Location (Column F) where there is people with the same Name (Column G) and Birthday year (Column H), as an example.

I tried INDEX + MATCH combined with COUNTIF or VLOOKUP but I either have only the first Location matching the criterias in the list, or an error.

Comment: Research the `FILTER()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unique Column Cells With Two-Column Duplicates

[image]

```
=LET(rCol,F2:F16,uCol1,G2:G16,uCol2,H2:H16,
    uAll,uCol1&","&uCol2,uOnce,UNIQUE(uAll,,1),rBol,ISERROR(XMATCH(uAll,uOnce)),
UNIQUE(FILTER(rCol,rBol)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column as unique key for each people in the first table. Maybe using some formula similar to this:

```
 =G2&H2
```

*(This is to create a cell based on values from columns Name & Birthday)*
Drag to apply for all cells in this column

Create a same column in the table for Location, then now you can use the VLOOKUP or INDEX-MATCH formula